# Boost Program_options config file comments

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

I have a program that reads a large number of variables from a configuration file using boost::program_options.  The configuration file is working and reading the values, however since there are many options in the file, I would like to document them in place.  For example I want the config file to look like:

```
# Here is a description of flag1
#    flag1 = true means blah blah blah
#    flag1 = false means ...
flag1=true
# Here is a description of flag 2
.
.
.
```

The issue is that I can not find documentation anywhere that describes a way to do this.  I am fairly certain that I could use something such as `a=` for my comment delimiter, and simply assign all the comments to a `std::vector<string>` to be thrown away after parsing, however I would like to know if there is a more appropriate way to handle comment lines in a configuration file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The documentation of `program_options` is really bad.

Fact is, it already supports comment lines starting with '#'. It throws these lines out. You don't have to do anything to make that work, it is done implicitely. It does not work with '//', etc.

Comment: That is what I wanted to hear, however it would be nice if they wrote it down somewhere.

Comment: @GodricSeer http://www.boost.org/doc/html/program_options/overview.html#idp120049504

Comment: I guess that was my oversight.  Thank you.